# Scrapy saved scraped data in csv in one line instead of multiple line

Tags: python, csv, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to **scrape** URL from a website and save the results in a csv file. But it is saving in one line only instead of multiple line.I tried to search for an answer in stackoverflow but in vain.Here is my file:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from uomscraprbot.items import UomscraprbotItem

class uomsitelinks(scrapy.Spider):
name = "uom"
allowed_domains = ["uom.ac"]
start_urls = [
"http://www.uom.ac.mu/"]

def parse(self, response):
   # print response.xpath('//body//li/a/@href').extract()
    item = UomscraprbotItem()
    item['url'] = response.xpath('//body//li/a/@href').extract()
    return item
```

i used : scrapy crawl uom -o uom.csv -t csv

```
i want it to save like this :
    www.a.com,
    www.b.com,
    www.c.com
and not 
www.a.com,www.b.com,www.c.com
```

where did i go wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process each URL separatelly:

```
def parse(self, response):
   # print response.xpath('//body//li/a/@href').extract()
   for item_url in response.xpath('//body//li/a/@href').extract():
       item = UomscrapebotItem()
       item['url'] = item_url
       yield item
```

Comment: Thank you, master ^^ , perfect answer